# cant able to select single value array in picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Having a single value array, I want to select that single value as textfiled text. After loading the pickerview I can't select that single value because, while selecting that single row value, view is scrolling and picker view is scrolling.

I can't select that single row value and I tried like this:

Picker view decleration

```
 ProjectListpicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(325, 90,   self.view.frame.size.width-500, 300)];
[ProjectListpicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[ProjectListpicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[ProjectListpicker reloadAllComponents];
ProjectListpicker.delegate = self;
ProjectListpicker.dataSource = self;
ProjectListpicker.tag = 1;
ProjectListpicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
[ProjectListpicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
ProjectListpicker.alpha = 0;
[CreatmeetingView addSubview:ProjectListpicker];
```

and in `didSelectRow` method

```
    Projectstxtfld.text=[PROJECT_NAMEArray objectAtIndex:row];
    _ProjId = [PROJECT_IDArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"propiid %@ %@",ProjectIdstr,_ProjId);
   [ProjectListpicker removeFromSuperview];
```

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: Check your code. You have added [ProjectListpicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES] twice.

Comment: ya..but i removed..extra lines...still same prb.. :(

Comment: Show me your full coding

Comment: in my picker view having only one value..when i am gng to select that single value..picker view is scrolling..i cant select that single value

Comment: Tamim Check my answer.

Comment: What happened did you check that?Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code

```
UIPickerView * ProjectListpicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    ProjectListpicker.frame = CGRectMake(5,70,150,300);
    ProjectListpicker.tag = 1;
    ProjectListpicker.delegate = self;
    ProjectListpicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:ProjectListpicker];

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"%@",_pickerData[row]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried sample project for your question.We have to use the delegate methods of PickerView.In arrayPicker I have only one data.That is iOS.When I Selected the row from the component it works perfectly and I get the selected row value in textField.

You have only one data in array so if want to directly set the selected row and get that value,use the below code.Here Select Row must be 0.

[ProjectListpicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

Instead of  [ProjectListpicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

```
UIPickerView * ProjectListpicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
ProjectListpicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 315, 320, 216);
ProjectListpicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
ProjectListpicker.dataSource = self;
ProjectListpicker.delegate = self;
[ProjectListpicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:ProjectListpicker];
```

## pragma mark -PickerView Delegate

```
// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return arrayPicker.count;
}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrayPicker objectAtIndex:row];
}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return 300;
}

// get Picker Value
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   @try {
     textFldPickerValue.text = [arrayPicker objectAtIndex:row];
     NSLog(@"The textFldPickerValue.text is - %@",textFldPickerValue.text);
   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {

   }
 }
```